# How do I create an email notification when my service is down?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What's the best way to get alerts trigger when a google compute service goes down? I know I can create a load balancing group with health check, but what if I just want a normal compute instance without the load balancer.

In AWS I can setup alarms, whats the equivalent in google cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack driver is the tool for GCP to monitor production issues.

Here is the documentation about service up monitoring.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/uptime-checks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create an alert with the [Monitoring Uptime Check service](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime)

- In the Google Cloud console, select Monitoring.
- In the navigation pane, click Uptime checks.
- Locate the uptime check that you want to monitor, click More , and select Add alert policy.
- In the navigation pane of the dialog, select Notifications and name.
- Add your notification channels, enter a name for the alerting policy. You can also add documentation that you want included in notifications.

For more and up to date informations, [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/uptime-alerting-policies?hl=en#create) will help.